# How to trigger app clip from website manually via custom url

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, safari, apple-appclips

I want App Clip to be launched from my website.

Currently App Clip is working perfectly fine because When I open my website on iPhone safari, it automatically shows a banner on top with a button that says: **Open App**

What I need is that I want to develop my custom banner with a button on my website from where I can trigger App Clip manually because sometimes that banner from App Clip appears a bit late, so I don't want to be dependent on that.

Any idea regarding this? I just need a direction or reference to some documentation that's all.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue previously and as I understand you can launch the App Clip only from smart banner, you can't use universal link as a trigger for opening the App Clip